# Is the scythe worth buying?

Tags: candy-box-2

I currently have 2.8m candies and I am saving for the scythe, but is it worth 5m? 
Isn't there any other boss or something I can kill and get a better weapon?

Answer (score 5):

The scythe is the weapon with the highest basic DPS in the game (~150).

If you beat the Teapot you can get the Giant Spoon, which has a base DPS of about 60% of the scythe but can be enchanted so that it just slightly edges into having the advantage in terms of DPS.

Comment: Thank you, that's really good info. 
But where do you find the Teapot? 
I 4,5m candies now. 
Thanks...

Comment: K Guys, now I have over 6m candeies and I'm going to buy the scythe

Comment: I have now the scythe and 1197 HP, 28m lollipops, only 5k candies and when I meet the nougat monster I can get it down to about 800HP but then I just die. What should I do? :O